# Function on previous result

Tags: haskell

I have  a function that a should run on a list. First, I have to compare the first two elements in the list  with the function, then compare the third element with the result of the first comparison and so on, so that the result is just one element. I feel like I should use iterate, but I couldn't make it work. How can I do this?

```
combineOption :: Cell -> Cell -> Cell
combineOption 'f' 'f' = 'f'
combineOption 'e' 'e' = 'e'
combineOption _ _ = 'u'

combineRow :: [Cell] -> [Cell] -> [Cell]
combineRow [] [] = []
combineRow l k = [ combineOption (l !! i) (k !! i) | i <- [0..(length(l)-1)] ]

combineLineOptions :: [[Cell]] -> [Cell]
combineLineOptions l = iterate ...                         <==================
```

where type Cell     = Char

Comment: What should the function do? Can you provide an example? What is its type? `iterate` looks wrong for this, but it's hard to suggest what to use without knowing what the function should do. It might be `foldl` or `scanl` or some variant.

Comment: Do you want to compare the fourth element with the result of the second comparison, and so on, so that the final result is just one element?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> have a function that a should run on a list. First, I have to compare the first two elements in the list with the function, then compare the third element with the result of the first comparison and so on, so that the result is just one element.

IIUC, that is exactly what [`foldl1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl1) does. E.g., if "comparison" is difference, then

```
Prelude Data.List> let l = [1, 2, 3]
Prelude Data.List> foldl1 (-) l
-4
```

"compares" 1 and 2, then "compares" the result with 3, so it is *1 - 2 - 3 = -4*.